# Stopping Karate mock server at the end of Integration testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, karate

I am using Karate to do integration testing for a Spring Boot app. The app consumes two other services (Service A and Service B) . I have written Karate mocks for Service A and B.  My integration tests are written as two different feature files. One of the feature is tested using Mocks for service A and B. Another feature uses Mocks for service B and Spring Contract Stubs for service A.

**Feature with only mocks**

```
 Feature: Test Some feature

  Background:
    * configure headers = { Content-Type: 'application/json' }
    * url baseUrl

 #Start up the mocks
  Scenario: Start the Mocks
    * karate.start({ mock: '../mock/service/service-a.feature', port: 9000})
    * karate.start({ mock: '../mock/service/service-b.feature', port: 9001})
```

**Feature with mocks and Spring Contract stubs**

```
 Feature: Test Some more features

  Background:
    * configure headers = { Content-Type: 'application/json' }
    * url baseUrl

 #Start up the mocks
  Scenario: Start the Mocks
    # Service A will use Spring Contract stubrunner. 
    * karate.start({ mock: '../mock/service/service-b.feature', port: 9001})
```

Now, when we run the tests, the second one fails saying that the port is already used.  I tried using `karate.stop(9000)` at the end of the feature file which is running first, but it does not help. Also,  I am not sure about the behaviour of this stop method.  Any suggestions to solve this problem ? Why the mock service is still running even after the tests are done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the mock should stop when the JVM exits - so I can't explain what's going on in your case. So maybe you should create a way to replicate and file a bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

I personally recommend starting your mocks from the unit-test Java code (typically the JUnit class) which means you can keep a reference to the mock and then call `stop()` on it. Even here, normally it is not mandatory, as the mock should terminate along with the JVM. Read the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-netty#embedding

Then, note that best-practice is to dynamically provision a port and then pass that to the test or any other consumers. Especially in CI-CD pipelines, this avoids the problem of the port in use or taking too much time to de-allocate.

And maybe the direct answer you are looking for. When you call `karate.start()` you get an object back which is of type `MockServer`. So you can keep a reference to it and call `stop()` on it when needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-netty#within-a-karate-test

For example:

```
* def server1 = karate.start('mock1.feature')
* def port1 = server1.port
# do some tests
* server1.stop()
```

Comment: I tried `server1.stop()` but it was giving me an error saying server1 is not defined. 

I managed to fix the issue by starting the mocks from JUnit code and stopping it once the test was executed. Thank you.

Comment: @Jay if there is an "issue" please raise a bug. but most likely you missed something